# hp update screwes stuff - black screen without acpi=off

Tags: suspend, bios, intel-wireless, acpi, hp-pavilion

you all know my previous two questions.  Summary  that booting  Ubuntu is giving black screen and kernel panic in uefi and legacy respectively. So changing boot  commandsin grub to acpi=off made it work, but brightness  wasn't changing and even wifi was 'disabled by hardware switch' i am remembering a flashback. long ago i updated the bios of this laptop (hp pavilion x360 13 inch i5) but before that i had booted Apricity OS (gnome 3 + arch linux) and it run with no problems. now i just tested it, and bam, same problem as before. balck screen. the bios screwed up something related to acpi. the worst thing is if i try to restore bios nothing happens, because i updated bios long ago, and no where to download old files. help me. where can i download original clean bios files the laptop comes with. :'(

EDIT: right. sorry dude-who-commented. it shows black screen in UEFI (no secureboot) and kernal panic in Legacy. 0x009 somthing. but now i have it sorted. it turns out EVil HP purposely released a bios update which screwed up acpi only for Linux. i downgraded but downloading the old bios and bam! ubuntu works! (typing from Kubuntu 16.04 Plasma 5)

Answer : Went to get drivers for  this laptop and clicked windows 8 instead of 10.  Found the old driver and installed! Now bam  Ubuntu loads! ,Although for future readers, acpi_osi= will also help, but brightness issues! That can be fixed by  some  programs though.

Comment: No, we don't know your previous questions. There are hundreds of new questions every day and most people only look at a tiny fraction of them. Could you please [edit] this question to include links to your previous questions and better yet a short summary? Also, can you please include the exact error message(s) during boot? Can you take a photo of them?

Comment: right. sorry dude-who-commented. it shows black screen in UEFI (no secureboot) and kernal panic in Legacy. 0x009 somthing. but now i have it sorted. it turns out EVil HP purposely released a bios update which screwed up acpi only for Linux. i downgraded byt downloading the old bios and bam! ubuntu works! (typing from Kubuntu 16.04 Plasma 5)

Comment: Worst written question ever. If you want help, at least have the common decency to give people the information they need and try to lay it out in some kind of understandable way. You're not helping yourself.

Comment: Sorry, but now  Idid all info. I am new  here and thought previous questions got linked or something. My bad. But now question solved!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

right. sorry dude-who-commented. it shows black screen in UEFI (no secureboot) and kernal panic in Legacy. 0x009 somthing. but now i have it sorted. it turns out EVil HP purposely released a bios update which screwed up acpi only for Linux. i downgraded Bios downloading the old bios and bam! ubuntu works! (typing from Kubuntu 16.04 Plasma 5)

but for you all who tryed this method and failed. there is an alternative. in grub menu before clicking nter press "e" and replace quite splash with acpi="Linux" or even acpi=    btu then brightness / wifi might now work. for me using this method brightness wasnt changing without help of external programs. thanks David Foerster for your kindness to helping this idiot and NutCracker! ;)